# ffmpeg concat drops audio frames

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, mp4, concatenation

I have an mp4 file and I want to take two sequential sections of the video out and render them as individual files, later recombining them back into the original video. For instance, with my video `video.mp4`, I can run

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ss 56 -t 4 out1.mp4
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ss 60 -t 4 out2.mp4
```

creating `out1.mp4` which contains 00:00:56 to 00:01:00 of `video.mp4`, and `out2.mp4` which contains 00:01:00 to 00:01:04. However, later I want to be able to recombine them again *quickly* (i.e., without reencoding), so I use the [concat demuxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer),

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i files.txt -c copy concat.mp4
```

where `files.txt` contains

```
file out1.mp4
file out2.mp4
```

which theoretically should give me back 00:00:56 to 00:01:04 of `video.mp4`, however there are always dropped audio frames where the concatenation occurs, creating a very unpleasant sound artifact, an audio *blip*, if you will.

[image: missing audio frames]

I have tried using `async` and `-af apad` on initially creating the two sections of the video but I am still faced with the same problem, and have not found the solution elsewhere. I have experienced this issue in multiple different use cases, so hopefully this simple example will shed some light on the real problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you export segments to MOV with PCM audio, then concat those but with re-encoding audio.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:a pcm_s16le -ss 56 -t 4 out1.mov
...
```

and then

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i files.txt -c:v copy concat.mp4
```

Comment: Sorry I was using -c copy.. I edited to include that. But your solution works! Can you explain why or provide any sources that would provide more details.

My assumption would be that originally I was encoding the audio as AAC, and the compression could have had at noticeable (when concatenating) effect at the boundaries. Would this be correct?

Comment: DCT-based audio codecs like MP3, AAC rely on neighbouring audio frames for decoding. At the start of the stream, there's a priming frame which serves that purpose. It has a negative timestamp, so during concat, its TS clashes with the final packets of the preceding file and it gets dropped by concat. PCM is self-contained for decoding, so doesn't suffer from this.

Comment: @Gyan Isn't there any "not DCT-Based" codec supported by the MP4 container so we don't need to change container just for that ?